{'code': 500, 'message': 'Internal error encountered.', 'status': 'INTERNAL'}
I have several projects in Google cloud that I am using to extract the data from Google Sheets using python. They run daily and refreshes the data in destination. Now this morning, one of the job failed and started throwing the error '{'code': 500, 'message': 'Internal error encountered.', 'status': 'INTERNAL'}' in both staging and prod env.
All the files in staging and prod are different as the one in staging are just copies of prod instance. I can not figure out what the issue is. the rest of my jobs are running fine, it's only this project that keeps throwing the issue. I have tried to run it manually as well.
It actually starts of fine and read couple of sheets before throwing this error. I have also implemented an exponential backoff algo to avoid quota issues
The issue is I can't provide any further details because i don't know what the issue is. Nothing's changed from the previous refresh, I have checked that.

Have you seen and tried this? Getting 500 error consistently on Google Sheets API. and if it's still not solving the issue, I would suggest you File a Bug in issuetracker. Like in this: SO

As stated in official documentation in Troubleshoot API errors: 500 errors  indicates that there is an  issue with the API itself.
